# Django cannot import name 'Response' from 'rest_framework'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django rest_framework project which is working fine. I am using pipenv and used it to install django_rest_framework. I can import functions such as `serializer` from rest_framework and use them without problems.

I would like to use rest_framework's `Response` class as given[here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/response.py) and described [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/response.py), so I wrote

```
from rest_framework import Response
```

This is not faulted by VSCode's syntax checks.

However, when I start the server I receive the message

```
 cannot import name 'Response' from 'rest_framework'
```

All help welcome

Comment: It should be: `from rest_framework.response import Response`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/#pulling-it-all-together) you need to import from response module like this:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
```